# pgfplots, dateplot: how to obtain xtick at given dates?

Tags: pgfplots, dateplot

the following mwe:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
datum,       s,      zt,      st,      u
2017-09-26,  9.2,    144,     80,      62
2017-09-29,  8.8,    141,     76,      64
2017-10-03,  8.4,    137,     77,      67
2017-10-06,  7.8,    136,     82,      53
2017-10-10,  9.1,    135,     80,      60
2017-10-13,  8.1,    139,     75,      61
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\centering
\begin{axis}[
    date coordinates in=x,
    xticklabel={\month-\day},
    x tick label style={rotate=45,anchor=north east},
    date ZERO=2017-09-26,
    grid=major, grid style=dashed,
    xlabel={Datum (mesec-dan)},
    ylabel={s},
]
\addplot table [x=datum, y=s, col sep=comma] {data.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

gives:

[image]

- i like that `xtick` are aligned with marks and if it is possible equidistant distributed regardless that dates are not (they are periodic, contain measurements are taken on each Tuesday and Friday)
  and that plot line is (consequently) not interrupted.
- is possible add days names (Tue, Fri) to `xtick` label on the way that i extend `data.cvs` with this names?

Comment: I do not get that output from your code, the plot line is without gaps.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. you have right. now i see, that in drawing images the `data.cvs` table has empty lines after each second table line which i deleted in my question. unintentional i solved part of my problems, however the main is still reaming (that thick are aligned with marks). i correct my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`xtick=data` works for dateplots as well, so simply adding that to your `axis` options will give a tick at each data point.

To have the data points equidistant, you can not use the dateplot stuff, but instead set `x expr=\coordindex`, and then use `xtick=data, xticklabels from table` to get whatever ticklabels you'd like. Here I used the date column, which you could modify to include the weekday.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
datum,       s,      zt,      st,      u
2017-09-26,  9.2,    144,     80,      62
2017-09-29,  8.8,    141,     76,      64
2017-10-03,  8.4,    137,     77,      67
2017-10-06,  7.8,    136,     82,      53
2017-10-10,  9.1,    135,     80,      60
2017-10-13,  8.1,    139,     75,      61
\end{filecontents*}

% xticklabels from table can't read comma separated file, I think, so read to macro
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{data.csv}\Data
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\centering
\begin{axis}[
    xtick=data,
    date coordinates in=x,
    xticklabel={\month-\day},
    x tick label style={rotate=45,anchor=north east},
    date ZERO=2017-09-26,
    grid=major, grid style=dashed,
    xlabel={Datum (mesec-dan)},
    ylabel={s},
]
\addplot table [x=datum, y=s, col sep=comma] {data.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\centering
\begin{axis}[
    xtick=data,
    xticklabels from table={\Data}{datum},
    x tick label style={rotate=45,anchor=north east},
    grid=major, grid style=dashed,
    xlabel={Datum (mesec-dan)},
    ylabel={s},
]
\addplot table [x expr=\coordindex, y=s] {\Data};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you very much for both solutions! they works fine and  i already used it my work :-) . now i see that i need to read `pgfplots` as well `pgfplotstable` manuals again ...